# How to manage memory with too many items on android recycleview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-memory

I am developing an android social media type application, where I have a multiple tab activity. The tabs are fragments using viewpager.I have a home screen with a recycler view. The post have images on them. I am having memory problem with the recyclerview for post. I am using firebase as a database if thats helpful. To load the imageview I am using glide and I am doing diskcache and skipping the memory caches.

Issues I am having are

1. When too many posts are loaded, recyclerview becomes slow and laggy (I know that there are other post with this but couldnt really found anything helpful).
2. When I click on a username from the post, a new profile activity starts which also have all the posts from that user, I am trying to find a way clear the homepage tab recyclerview memory but struggleing with how to.

To solve the first problem, I have set up an onscrolllistner that loads 10 new post everytime you are near the end of the post list. The recycler view adapter currently loads 20 items initially and then so on.but  I am not sure how to clear the old posts in an efficient way since I want the user to be able to scroll up.

To solve the second problem, In the homescreen fragment, when I launch the new activity, the onPause() function gets called. In the onpause() function I tried setting the list to empty, recyclerview adapter to null, recylerview to null but nothing has worked. In the android profiler tool, I see that I am using 200 mb memory, and when I start the new activity, it adds another 100 mb or so. I tried manual garbage collections but it doesnt work either. To be specific, native memory jumps up in the profiler. Ive tested and made sure that was only because of the images in the recyclerview.

I am not sure why when I set recyclerview, adapter and the post list to null, why the images from posts are still being held in the memory.

Comment: You can try onViewRecycled in the adapter class. It is for memory clear maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Glide caches the images
2. To load multiple post check paging library
3. When moving to detail fragment and clearing the reacyclerview of home fragment , I would not recommend this as next time user switches to home tab ,the user will not have previous state saved which he left  previously.

Comment: Thanks for reply. For 1. I know glide caches images and it has a function to clear memory, tried that but didnt help.   2. I didnt think of this. will try that but wont I run into the same problem of having too many post or will it let me control how many posts are on the view?    3. Yh I thought about that but I think there is a way to save recylcerview state or something like that ? beside I was more lost on why setting the adapter and recyclerview to null didnt clean up memory?

Comment: paging library worked like a charm for loading tons of posts.

Comment: Glad it helped you !